# NullpointerException when testing a controller method

Tags: java, testing, junit, jmock

Here is a controller method I'm about to test with JUnit and JMock.

```
public String myMethod(ModelMap model, Principal principal,
                        @PathVariable MyObject obj) {
  if (obj != null) {
    Student student = getStudent(principal);
    if (check(obj, student)) {
      model.addAttribute(student).addAttribute(obj);
      return "page";
    }
  }
  return REDIR;
}


private boolean check(MyObject obj, Student student) {
  return student.getStudentNumber().longValue() == obj.getStudent().getStudentNumber().longValue();
}
```

My test

```
final StudentService studentService = context.mock(StudentService.class);

public void test() throws Exception {
  ModelMap model = new ModelMap();
  final MyObject = new myObject();

  context.checking(new Expectations() {
    {
      oneOf(studentService).getByNumber(SecurityHelper.getStudentNumberOf(Helper.getTestPrincipal()));
      will(returnValue(mockStudent));
    }
  });

  controller.myMethod(model, Helper.getTestPrincipal(), obj);
}
```

When running test, I get a `NullPointerExeption` which points to check-method. Any idea where that comes from? Is it because I lack some expectation? Student and obj are not interfaces to be mockable. I'm new with this. Which is the best way to track these kind of testing errors?

Comment: Please post your stacktrace. Also, please show the code in your test where you mock the `studentService`.

Comment: I added the mocking. Tracktrace points to line number on controller method where is the if clause and on test where I call controller.test-method

Comment: One way to pinpoint null pointer is to split statement up to use temp variables. That is, when you have `method1(methdo2()).method3()...`, change that to `temp2 = method2(); temp1 = method1(temp2); temp1.method3()...`.

Comment: None of the parametres given to check method is null.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly, this is the line that throws an exception:

```
return student.getStudentNumber().longValue() == obj.getStudent()
    .getStudentNumber().longValue();
```

So the exception can come from several places:

1. `studen` or `obj` are null.
2. `student.getStudentNumber()` returns null.
3. `obj.getStudent()` returns null
4. `obj.getStudent().getStudentNumber()` returns null.

Do a System.out on all of these statements and see which is null.